# Allow Office viewer in my htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I try to use different viewers on my website and keep my files kind of "protected.

For ex with google viewer I do :

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://www.example.com/docs/'+file+'&#038;embedded=true" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

And in my .htaccess I put :

```
allow from google.com
```

That works just fine.

I'm trying to do the same with Office viewer :

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://www.example.com/docs/"+file+"' width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0'></iframe>

allow from live.com
```

But I get an error message that Office viewer can't access the file, so I guess Office viewer tries to access the file through another domain than live.com, but I don't know how to find this info or how to monitor it, can anyone help ?

Comment: You should try all the domains. Technically live.com is not the same as view.officeapps.live.com. Those both have different IP addresses because subdomains are domains and can have different IP address. Use the actual domain it's coming from in the rules. `view.officeapps.live.com` and `officeapps.live.com`

Comment: Thanks. Well actually google doc viewer is using apis.google.com and docs.google.com ... and by adding only google.com it works... but as you said, maybe google is using the same ip for its subdomains. Will try and let you know, but I figured out from the console timeline that office.net is also called by Office doc viewer.

Comment: Nope it didn't work either...